# What is default isolation level hibernate uses if not explicitly set?

Tags: hibernate, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have an application that uses hibernate version 3.6.4, and c3p0 version 0.9.1.2 for connection pooling. My underlying RDBMS is MySql version 5.0.67.

My installation of MySql indicates that the default transaction isolation level is "REPEATABLE-READ" (4):

```
mysql> select @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation | @@tx_isolation  |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ       | REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

I have not changed or configured the transaction isolation level within hibernate.cfg.xml or anywhere within my application. From the app, I use the following code to print configuration:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = getSession().connection().getMetaData();
System.out.println("Default Tx Isolation: " + meta.getDefaultTransactionIsolation());
System.out.println("Current Tx Isolation: " + getSession().connection().getTransactionIsolation());
```

And I get the following results:

```
Default Tx Isolation: 2 (=READ_COMMITTED)
Current Tx Isolation: 4 (=REPEATABLE_READ)
```

So, my questions are the following:

1. Where did the "2" value came from? Since the default is the REPEATABLE_READ, why *getDefaultTransactionIsolation()* returns READ_COMMITTED?
2. What is the isolation level that hibernate uses after all? REPEATABLE_READ or READ_COMMITTED?
3. I thought that when no isolation level is set, hibernate should use the underlying database's default. Is this true? Maybe the jbdc driver implementation sets a default on its own and hibernate uses this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

looks like  meta.getDefaultTransactionIsolation());
is hardcoded in the implementation of DatabaseMetaData in the mysql driver

public class DatabaseMetaData implements java.sql.DatabaseMetaData
lines....

```
1475    public int getDefaultTransactionIsolation() throws java.sql.SQLException JavaDoc {
1476        if (this.conn.supportsIsolationLevel()) {
1477            return java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED;
1478        } else {
1479            return java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE;
1480        }
1481    }
```

so i'd bet and trust getSession().connection().getTransactionIsolation()

Comment: How would you achieve the same thing with hibernate 4 since connection() has been deprecated?

Comment: Like this:

((((SessionFactoryImplementor)getSession().getSessionFactory())                   .getJdbcServices().getConnectionProvider().getConnection().getTransactionIsolation()
// method is also deprecated and causes "connection pool exausted" error, but working.

I think actual method is:

getSession.doWork(new Work() { @Override void execute(Connection conn) { /* working with conn */ }} );

But I 'm not checking if it's working during session or not.

Comment: In Hibernate 5 it's `((org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor)session.getSessionFactory()).getJdbcServices().getBootstrapJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection().getTransactionIsolation()`